# How to move elements from a set to a vector efficiently?

Tags: c++11, vector, set

I have a `std::set<vector<int>>` from which I would like to move (not copy) elements to a `std::vector<vector<int>>`. How do I do this?

I tried using move (which I use to move between vectors) with the following piece of code but it won't compile.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    set<vector<int>> res;
    vector<int> first = {1,2,3};
    vector<int> second = {4,5,6};
    res.insert(first);
    res.insert(second);
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    for(auto i : res){
        ans.emplace_back(ans.end(),move(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't the compiler give you any message about why it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `set<T>` does not contain `T`s; it contains `const T`s. As such, you *cannot* simply move objects out of it.

Comment: Someone answered here previously using `push_back` and `move`. What does that do?

Comment: @zorro: It does a copy. You can prove that by [using the same code, only with a non-copyable type](http://ideone.com/q1tjAk). You naturally get a compile error about attempting to call a `delete`d function.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of reasons why we still may need const_cast sometimes:

```
for(auto& i : res){
    ans.emplace_back(ans.end(),move(const_cast<T&>(i)));
}
```

No point to do it for int elements though.